# Scala: String "+" vs "++"

Tags: java, string, scala, operators

I am new to Scala and I have seen code for concatenating Strings in Scala like this:

```
"test " ++ "1"
```

And I have tested, and it is also written in [Scala Doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps)

```
"test " + "1"
```

So my understanding is that `+` is like the Java String `+` but `++` is more powerful, can take in more types of parameters. Also `++` seems to be universal to other things like List. I want to know if my understanding is correct. and any other differences? When should one over another just for string concatenation?

Comment: In addition to the answers, I recommend not to use `+` any longer. It will most likely be deprecated and ultimately removed. Now Scala has string interpolation which is the preferred way to compose strings. Using `++` might be slower, but I think it is a good alternative, syntactically clear and in alignment with Scala's collections.

Comment: @0__ 2 hours ago, + is from Java string right? I mean in that case would Scala keep it for Scala strings?

Comment: `+` is not defined on the `java.lang.String` API, in Java it is merely a syntactic sugar for running a string builder. This is the same in Scala, where String catenation with `+` is defined by the compiler even in the absence of of `Predef.any2stringadd`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664274/how-to-unimport-string-operator-in-scala

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It helps to take a look in [`scala.Predef`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Predef$) to see what exactly is going on.

If you check there, you see that `String` in Scala is just an alias for `java.lang.String`. In other words, the `+` method on a `String` gets translated into Java's `+` operator.

So, if a Scala `String` is just a Java `String`, how does the `++` method even exist, you might ask. (Well, I'd ask, at least.) The answer is that there's an implicit conversion from `String` to `WrappedString` provided by the `wrapString` method, which is also in `Predef`.

Notice that `++` takes any `GenTraversableOnce` instance and adds all of the elements in that instance to the original `WrappedString`. (Note that the docs incorrectly state that the method returns a `WrappedString[B]`. This has to be incorrect, because `WrappedString` doesn't take type parameters.) What you'll get back is either a `String` (if the thing you add is a `Seq[Char]`) or some `IndexedSeq[Any]` (if it's not).

Here are some examples:

If you add a `String` to a `List[Char]`, you get a String.

```
scala> "a" ++ List('b', 'c', 'd')
res0: String = abcd
```

If you add a `String` to a `List[String]`, you get an `IndexedSeq[Any]`. In fact, the first two elements are `Char`s, but the last three are `String`s, as the follow-up call shows.

```
scala> "ab" ++ List("c", "d", "e")
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Any] = Vector(a, b, c, d, e)

scala> res0 map ((x: Any) => x.getClass.getSimpleName)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(Character, Character, String, String, String)
```

Finally, if you add a `String` to a `String` with `++`, you get back a `String`. The reason for this is that `WrappedString` inherits from `IndexedSeq[Char]`, so this is a convoluted way of adding a `Seq[Char]` to a `Seq[Char]`, which gives you back a `Seq[Char]`.

```
scala> "abc" + "def"
res0: String = abcdef
```

As Alexey noted, neither of these is a very subtle tool, so you're probably better off using [string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) or a [`StringBuilder`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder) unless there's a good reason not to.

Answer (score 4):

`String` is a `TraversableLike`, which means it can be decomposed into a sequence of elements ( characters ). That is where `++` comes from, otherwise you can not do `++` on String. `++` would only work when the right hand side of it ( or the parameter to that function ), is a de-composable type ( or a traversable ).

Now how does `String` become a `TraversableLike`? This where the implicits defined in `Predef` come into play. One of the implicit converts normal `String` into a `WrappedString` where `WrappedString.canBuildFrom` has all the glue which basically works in this way:

`WrappedString.canBuildFrom` -> `StringBuilder` -> `StringLike` -> `IndexedSeqOptimized` -> `IndexedSeqLike` -> `SeqLike` -> `IterableLike` -> `TraversableLike`

Since the implicits defined in Predef are already in scope, it is possible to write code like this:

```
"test " ++ "1"
```

Now your questions:

> I want to know if my understanding is correct. and any other differences?

Yes your understanding is in the right direction.

> When should one over another just for string concatenation?

For string concatenation, clearly `"test " + "1"` is creating less objects, and less number of function calls. However, I would always prefer string interpolation like so:

```
val t1 = "test"
val t2 = "1"
val t3 = s"$t1 $t2"
```

which is more readable.

For more details:

- Scala source code: https://github.com/scala/scala
- http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html

Answer (score 2):

> So my understanding is that + is like the Java String + but ++ is more powerful, can take in more types of parameters

The thing is, `+` on Strings is more powerful in this sense: it can take any parameters at all, just like in Java. This is often considered a misfeature (especially since it also works with strings on the right), but we are pretty much stuck with it. `++` is, as you say, a general collection method and more type-safe (`"test " ++ 1` won't compile).

> When should one over another just for string concatenation?

I'd prefer `+`. However, for many (I'd even say most) usages what you want is neither: use [string interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) instead.

```
val n = 1
s"test $n"
```

And of course, when building up a string from *many* parts, use [`StringBuilder`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder).

Comment: You are right about that "+" is more powerful but I just want to confirm that implicit conversion from int to string happened in Java right?

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no implicit conversion involved. In Java, what happens is so-called [string conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1); in Scala `String` is considered to have a `def +(other: Any)` method, so it can take any argument. Implicit conversion only happens if a non-`String` value without a suitable `+` method is on the left and `String` on the right (see [`any2stringAdd`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$$any2stringadd)), and in this case it happens in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

++ isn't necessarily "more powerful", but it is used in general as a concatenation/appending operation.  However, it does not perform assignment.  IE `listX ++ y` will append to listX, but `i++` will not increment integer i  (since that's assigning to the variable versus mutating).

That's my understanding at least.  I'm not a Scala expert.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implicit conversion from `String` to `StringOps` in `scala.Predef`. The `++` method is defined in the `StringOps` class. So whenever you do `str1 ++ str2` the scala compiler is essentially (at from the perspective of the coder) wrapping `str1` in a `StringOps` and calling the `++` method of `StringOps`. Note that `StringOps` is essentially a sort of `IndexedSeq`, so the `++` operator is very flexible, e.g.

```
"Hello, " ++ "world!"  //results in "Hello, world" with type String
"three" ++ (1 to 3)    //results in Vector('t', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e', 1, 2, 3) with type IndexedSeq[AnyVal]
```